# fiber of a map into Grassmanian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, grassmannians

Suppose $R\subset K=K_0\supset K_1\supset K_2\supset...\supset K_{n-1}\supset K_n=\{0\}$ are all vector spaces with $\dim R\cap K_i=r_i$ where $r_i$ are some fixed numbers. Suppose $O\subset Gr(r_0,\sum l_i)$is the set of all $R$ satisfies these conditions, where $Gr(r_0,\sum l_i)$ is the set of all $r$ dimensional subspaces in a vector space of dimension $\sum l_i$, and $l_i=dim(K_{i-1}/K_i)$ Then we have a map$$O\longrightarrow Gr(r_{n-1},l_n)\times Gr(r_{n-2}-r_{n-1},l_{n-1})\times...\times Gr(r_0-r_1,l_1)\\ R\longmapsto R\cap K_{n-1},(R\cap K_{n-2})/(R\cap K_{n-1}),...,, (R\cap K_2)/ (R\cap K_1),R/(R\cap K_1)$$ Obviously this is a projection and the author claimed it is an affine fibration of rank $$t=(r_{n-2}-r_{n-1})(l_n-r_{n-1})+(r_{n-3}-r_{n-2})(l_{n-1}+l_n-r_{n-2})+...+(r_0-r_1)(l_2+...+l_n-r_1)$$
But I have no idea how to get this, hope somebody can help me.

Comment: It seems you're referring to a construction from a specific book or paper. Would you mind providing a citation in your question?

Comment: It also seems that $l_i$ , which is not defined in your question, was intended to be the dimension of $K_{i-1}/K_i$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, yes $l_i$ is the dimension of $K_{i-1}/K_i$

Answer (score 1):

I guess there must be some numerical conditions on the $r_i$ and the $l_i$ for this to be true, but I can give you an illustrating example where the fiber is indeed affine.

Assume $n=2$ and that $$\dim R + \dim K_1 - \dim K_0 = r_1.$$ Let $$\Phi : O \rightarrow \operatorname{Gr}(r_1,\dim K_1)$$ be the projection map. Let $L$ in $\operatorname{Gr}(r_1, \dim K_1)$. The fiber of $\Phi$ over $L$ is $$\{R \in \operatorname{Gr}(r_0,K_0), \ R \cap K_1 = L\}.$$ Taking the quotient by $L$, we get that the fiber of $\Phi$ over $L$ is $$\{R',\operatorname{Gr}(r_0-r_1,K_0/L), \ R' \cap K_1/L = 0\}.$$ Since $$\dim R' + \dim K_1/L = \dim K_0/L$$ (by the extra numerical hypothesis I made), this last set is known as a Schubert cell. You can see that it is isomorphic to the vector space of linear projections from $K_0/L$ to $K_1/L$. Hence it is affine.

Comment: If n=2 shouldn't $$\Phi: O\rightarrow Gr(r_1,dim K_1)\times Gr(r_0-r_1, dimK_0/K_1)$$

Comment: with the dimensional hypothesis I made, we have $K_0/K_1 = R/(R \cap K_1)$, so that the second map is irrelevant in my situation. But you're right, it's good point, I hadn't noticed this last factor of the projection map which is precisely made to drop the numerical assumption.

Comment: why the last set is isomorphic to the vector space of linear projections from $K_0/L$ to $K_1/L$?

Comment: @236626 : well that is first year undergraduate linear algebra...

Comment: why the last factor gives you $dim K_0/K_1= dim R/(R\cap K_1)$?